# Android Menu Button in Activity content

Tags: android, menuitem

My question:
How to get such effect like in Google Play?

Here are the pictures :

[image] 
[image]

Red circles shows what I mean.

Comment: Voted to close as this is too broad of a question showing no research effort. However, you may want to look at [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As codeMagic commented, the correct way to do this is to use `PopupMenu` as follows:

```
ImageView mOptions = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image); //the image you want press and get the menu to pop up on
mOptions.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu menu = new PopupMenu(this, view); 
                MenuInflater inflate = menu.getMenuInflater();
                inflate.inflate(R.menu.simple_menu, menu.getMenu()); //inflate simple_menu, a menu list you created in resources
                menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        //handle menu clicks in here
                        return false;
                    }

                });
                menu.show();
            }

});
```